# esri leaflet calcite geojson popup binding

Tags: popup, esri-leaflet

I am binding a popup to the results of a query, that is working fine. My problem is whenever the map changes (pan, zoom, etc.) the popups no longer work. Is there something I should be doing in a different way?

To reproduce: Select one of the parcel types, click on a popup, pan the map, try again.

http://argis.ualr-iea.org/GFPB/

Comment: i can't reproduce your error in a simplified repro case: http://jsbin.com/nubapef/edit?html,output. this makes your own .css is the most likely culprit.

Comment: Thanks for the troubleshooting tip John, I will dig through it.